# R Data Table not updating binary research

Tags: r, data.table

I often use the site when I ask myself questions, but it's my first time writing a question here. Let's look at that reproductible example to understand my problem.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
table1 <- data.table(a=sample(10000,10,TRUE),b=sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10,TRUE))
table1
table1[b==TRUE]
set(table1,3L,"b",TRUE)
table1
table1[b==TRUE]
```

The problem is, when I update the b-variable of the third entry of the table, It doesn't seem to be updated when I try to make a research in the table. In the last line of my code, I would expect the third entry to appear but it doesn't.

I hope my question is clear. I apologize for my poor English, I do my best.

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding parentheses, like `table1[(b==TRUE)]` There's a bug in version 1.9.4. You can upgrade to the development version of the package following instructions here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation Anyway, this was a well-formed first question :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The third entry appears for me. (edit: appears this is something that's been fixed as I'm running `1.9.5`)

Comment: hmmm, I never seen `table1[(b==TRUE)]` before, why not just `table1[(b)]`?

Comment: Woaw, I have an answer 5 minutes after posting my question. That's efficiency! Thank you guys!

Comment: That long?  Dang, we're slipping.